# Batch load files to R while excluding bad rows using 'sqldf'

Tags: r, import, sqldf

I have a chunk of R code that recursively loads, tidies, and exports all .txt files in a directory (files are tab-delimited but I used read.fwf to drop columns).  The code works for .txt files with complete data after 9 lines of unnecessary headers.  However, when I expanded the code to the directory with the full set of .txt files (>500), I found that some of the files have bad rows embedded within the data (essentially, automated repeats of a few header lines, sample available [here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/ws5918ddm3xzu9e/2008NOV28_MORNING_trunc.txt?dl=0)).  I have tried just loading all rows, both good and bad, with the intent of removing the bad rows from within R, but get error messages about column numbers.

**Original error: Batch load using read.fwf** (Note: I only need the first three columns from each .txt file)

```
setwd("C:/Users/Seth/Documents/testdata")  
library(stringr)
filesToProcess <- dir(pattern="*.txt", full.names=T)

listoffiles <- lapply(filesToProcess, function(x) read.fwf (x,skip=9, widths=c(10,20,21), col.names=c("Point",NA,"Location",NA,"Time"), stringsAsFactors=FALSE))
Error in scan(file, what, nmax, sep, dec, quote, skip, nlines, na.strings,  : 
  line 344 did not have 5 elements    #error from bad rows
```

Next I tried pre-processing the data to exclude the bad rows using 'sqldf'.

**Fix attempt 1: Batch pre-process using 'sqldf'**

```
library(sqldf)
listoffiles <- lapply(filesToProcess, function(x) read.csv.sql(x, sep="\t", 
+ skip=9,field.types=c("Point","Location","Time","V4","V5","V6","V7","V8","V9"),
+ header=F, sql = "select * from file where Point = 'Trackpoint' "))
Error in scan(file, what, nmax, sep, dec, quote, skip, nlines, na.strings,  : 
  line 1 did not have 9 elements
```

**Fix attempt 2: Single file pre-process using 'sqldf'**

```
test.v1 <- read.csv.sql("C:/Users/Seth/Documents/testdata/test/2008NOV28_MORNING_Hunknown.txt", 
+ sep="\t", skip=9,field.types=c("Point","Location","Time","V4","V5","V6","V7","V8","V9"),
+ header=F, sql = "select * from file where Point = 'Trackpoint' ")
Error in scan(file, what, nmax, sep, dec, quote, skip, nlines, na.strings,  : 
  line 1 did not have 9 elements
```

I'd prefer to do this cleanly and use something like 'sqldf' or 'dplyr, but am open to pulling in all rows and then post-process within R.  My questions: How do I exclude the bad rows of data during import?  Or, how do I get the full data set imported and then remove the bad rows within R?

Comment: You should realize that the `batch-file` tag have _no_ relation with your problem, and delete it...

Comment: Thanks, @Aacini.  It was suggested by Stack and I was mistaken to include it.

Comment: `read.sql.csv` supports the `filter=` keyword.  See `?read.csv.sql` and `?sqldf``.

Comment: Thanks for the direction, @G.Grothendieck.  I looked into that but couldn't find any examples that didn't use perl or gawk, and I need a simple solution (I'm an end user, don't know much programming code, and am simply trying to process the files to pass on to someone else).  I thought the 'sql=' statement would do the subsetting and that my error was coming from somewhere else in the function.

Comment: FAQ#13 on the sqldf home page https://github.com/ggrothendieck/sqldf has an example on the home page but see my answer for a simple approach.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here are a few ways.  They all make use of the fact that  the good lines all contain the degree symbol (octal 260) and junk lines do not.  In all of these we have assumed that columns 1 and 3 are to be dropped.

**1)** This code assumes you have `grep` but you may need to quote the first argument of `grep` depending on your shell.  (On Windows, to get `grep` you would need to install [Rtools](https://cran.r-project.org/bin/windows/Rtools/) and under a normal Rtools install `grep` is found here: `C:\\Rtools\bin\grep.exe`.  The Rtools bin directory would have to be placed on your Windows path or else the entire pathname would need to be used when referencing the Rtools grep.)  These comments only apply to (1) and (4) as (2) and (3) do not use the system's grep.

```
File <- "2008NOV28_MORNING_trunc.txt"

library(sqldf)
DF <- read.csv.sql(File, header = FALSE, sep = "\t", eol = "\n",
       sql = "select V2, V4, V5, V6, V7, V8, V9 from file",
       filter = "grep [\260] ")
```

**2)** You may not need sqldf for this:

```
DF <- read.table(text = grep("\260", readLines(File), value = TRUE), 
        sep = "\t", as.is = TRUE)[-c(1, 3)]
```

**3)** Alternately try the following which is more efficient than (2) but involves specifying the `colClasses` vector:

```
colClasses <- c("NULL", NA, "NULL", NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA)
DF <- read.table(text = grep("\260", readLines(File), value = TRUE), 
        sep = "\t", as.is = TRUE, colClasses = colClasses)
```

**4)** We can also use the system's `grep` with `read.table.  The comments in (1) about grep apply here too:

```
DF <- read.table(pipe(paste("grep [\260]", File)), 
        sep = "\t", as.is = TRUE, colClasses = colClasses)
```

Comment: Many thanks @G.Grothendieck!  These solved my problem!